# How to prevent from form submission when email exists error and how to set value in form itself without getting reset

Tags: reactjs, redux

The below code shows the form submit function. the form gets submitted but when email exist error occurs the form gets reset. how to prevent form getting reset?.

```
submit = values => {
  // print the form values to the console

  let formValues = {
    clu_first_name: values.clu_first_name,
    clu_last_name: values.clu_last_name,
    clu_email: values.clu_email,
    clu_sec_email: " ",
    // "clu_state":0,
    // "clu_city":0,
    // "clu_zip":0,
    // "clu_address":null,
    clu_contact: values.clu_contact,
    lgn_password: values.clu_pass,
    cli_id: client_id, // SRM id
    cat_id: values.cat_id,
    dep_id: values.dep_id,
    usr_id: usr_ID,
    clu_id: values.clu_id
  };

  console.log("formValues-fmp", formValues);
  let decodeFormValues = { json: JSON.stringify(formValues) };
  this.setState({ formSubmitting: true });

  fetch(
    `${Utils.getApiBaseUrl()}/fmp/client/addClientUser`,
    Utils.getPostOptions(decodeFormValues)
  )
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status == 1) {
        toast.success(" Successfully created.", {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
          autoClose: 3000
        });
        this.fetchUserList(client_id);
        this.setState({ formSuccess: true, formError: false, opened: false });
      } else {
        toast.error("Email exists", {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
          autoClose: 3000
        });
        this.setState({
          formError: true,
          formSuccess: false,
          errorText: res.data
        });
      }
      this.setState({ formSubmitting: false });
    });
};
```

Below is my form code, here because of `onsubmitsuccess` it get reset, I want to get reset after success if any error occurs the form must have the values.

```
const afterSubmit = (result, dispatch) => dispatch(reset("createuser"));
CreateUserForm = reduxForm({
  form: "createuser",
  multipartForm: true,
  onSubmitSuccess: afterSubmit
})(CreateUserForm);
```

Comment: Does the page reload on submit? If so you'll need to add `e.preventDefault()` to the submit handler. [See here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: page does not get reload, form gets reset while getting error, how to prevent from reset - @Toby